# Responsive sticky hamburger navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive sticky navigation bar which will shorten when the screen gets too small (for mobile). The navigation bar works fine without the hamburger bars on my laptop, but i am struggling to implement the following code on W3C with my code.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

the following is a link to jsfiddle with the HTML, CSS and Javascript code I am using.

**HTML**

https://jsfiddle.net/cpeotvsf/25/

below is my code

```
<body>
  <div class="top-container">
      <h1>testing header</h1>
      <h3>Scroll down to see learn more.</h3>
  </div>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <div class="navbar" id="Mynavbar">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Services 
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Red or Black Tarmac Drives and Paths</a>
          <a href="#">Fencing and Gates</a>
          <a href="#">Shingle and Coloured Gravels</a>
          <a href="#">Drainage Work</a>
          <a href="#">Patios and Crazy Paving</a>
          <a href="#">Block Paved Driveways and Paths</a>
          <a href="#">Turfing and Artificial Grass</a>
          <a href="#">Brick and Purbeck Stone Walls</a>
          <a href="#">Decking and Rockeries</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#home">Gallary</a>
      <a href="#home">Before and After</a>
      <a href="#home">Testimonials</a>
      <a href="#home">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionn()">
         <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

The CSS and Javascript I am using are in the jsfiddle link above

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you really want which error do you want to correct??

Comment: just a point in the right direction, I can currently get the 'hamburger' bar to show when the screen is reduced, but when i click on it, my other headers do not show.. I must be overlooking something small but cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js is fine but jsFiddle keeps the script's load-type *on load* rather than at the bottom of the page so the onClick can't find the following function:

```
function myFunctionn() {
    // place this script below your body content.
}
```

---

To make the above function run properly in *jsFiddle*, just click **JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS) ▼** and change the **load type** to *bottom of body* then re-run the script.

---

jsFiddle with **load type** updated: https://jsfiddle.net/cpeotvsf/35/